# Output to same view from different controllers

Tags: php, html, laravel

Is it possible to output to the same view from multiple controllers. I have one view called 'dashboard'. I have two variables: `$users` and `$friends`. I want to send data to these variables from different controllers. Do I need to add two controllers to the same route?

The view:

```
<div class="panel friendlist" id="friendlist">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Result List</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($friends as $friend)
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="">{{ $friend->username }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row posts">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-3-offset">
            <header><h3>other posts</h3></header>
            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <article class="post">
                <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
                <div class="info">Posted by {{ $post->user->username }} on {{ $post->created_at }}</div>
```

The post controller:

```
public function getDashboard()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
        return view('dashboard',['posts' => $posts]);
    }
```

The friend controller:

```
public function getFriends()
    {
        $friends = Auth::user()->friends()->where('status','accepted')->get();

        return view('dashboard',['friends' => $friends]);
    }
```

Current route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard',[
        'uses' => 'PostController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'dashboard',
        'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);
```

Comment: how you can add multiple controllers to the same route? Yes you can use a view in as many controllers as you want.

Answer (score 0):

@Amartya Barua, you can use view composer to share some variables to multiple views https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views, Or you can create BaseService, and write reusable getters and inject BaseService to your controller, in this way you can able to access required getters to your Controller, if any question comment my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing you can do is

1. First create one Model and in this model create two functions for this two variable values.
2. In Controller where you want to use dashboard as view add model to your controller and simply pass call function of that model and pass this function values to view.